# Trigonometric problem?

Tags: trigonometry

This may be really easy but is giving a hard time. I'm a beginner at trigonometry so hope I can understand it.

1. If $\sin{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos{\frac{x}{2}}= 1.4$, then $\sin{x}=?$
2. If $\sin{a}-\cos{a}=a$, then $\sin(2a)=?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with these questions is finding the way to start.  We'll need two identities
$$\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1, \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sin(2t) = 2\sin t \cos t$$
All we have to do is square each side of the equation
$$\left(\sin \frac{x}{2} + \cos \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 = (1.4)^2$$
A bit of algebra gives
$$\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} + \cos^2\frac{x}{2} + 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} = 1.96$$
$$1 + 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} = 1.96$$
$$2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} = 0.96$$
And with the second identity, 
$$\sin\left( 2\times\frac{x}{2}\right) = 0.96$$
Thus
$$\sin x = 0.96$$
The same principle applies to the second problem